# Addressing multi-dimensional arraylists

Tags: java

I'm attempting a radix sort but I'm having trouble addressing arraylists of arraylists. The list has 10 spaces, each with a bucket of size n.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(10);
ArrayList<Integer> bucket = new ArrayList<>();
bucket.add(99);
list.add(bucket);
list.add(bucket);
list.get(0).add(12); (6)
```

When I attempt to add in a value using (6) it adds 12 for each arraylist within list (presumably because they are both buckets). How can I initialize the arraylist properly such that I treat each arraylist in list independently? And would I access the elements of each arraylist in list in a similar fashion?

Comment: The 2 buckets you add are the same (point to the same arraylist). You need to instantiate a new arraylist each time (bucket = new ArrayList();) before adding it to your list.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

  list.add(new ArrayList<>());

}
```

You can set a size for each bucket if you want also - I think by passing the desired size to the ArrayList constructor

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

:)

Comment: Great, thanks. And this exercise supplied to me isn't strictly homework as its unassessed

Answer (score 0):

When you add 12 to the `ArrayList` in `list`, you are adding to a referenced `ArrayList`, which in this case is `bucket`.  `list.get(0)` and `list.get(1)` will both return a reference to the same `ArrayList`, `bucket`.